# Invoking node controllers functions to angular controllers and services

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, k-means, meanjs

I am using angular as my front and nodejs as backend, now I need to get customer details in my site. In this I've routed api in app as /customerdetails, which I have tested in restclient, as "http://localhost:3000/customerdetails/my accesstoken" and able to get customer details which I have queried..

Now I need to get this in frontend (i.e angular )...

Here is my code:

In `public/module/service`:

```
  use strict';

    angular.module('customerdetails').factory('Customer', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {

            return $resource('customerdetails', null, {

            listCust: {
                method: 'GET',

        }`enter code here`
    });
```

} ]);

Also `listCust` - its a function which i have called in server end (`app/module/controllers`)

In `public/module/controller`:

For this how to code controllers in angular.

Thnaks&regards,

Indu

Comment: It;s not clear what you are asking. Do you want someone to write your `listCust` method for you?

Comment: no.. i need to know how to call  my backend api /customerdetails in frontend angularjs  controller and service...since i can able to get data from backend by testing  in postman , i want to invoke those in frontend...

Comment: listCust is a function  which i have  written my query to db to retrieve all customerdetails. and located in my app/module/controllers.

Comment: Here I need to get all customer details without passing any param...how to do this in angular controllers?